# something's wrong with my cakePHP save method

Tags: php, cakephp

i have a method inside a model, to do a simple save (insert to database), first it finds any users which meet certain conditions, and then insert certain info to another table to each of those found users, here's the code:

```
function save_emails(){
    App::import('Model', 'User');
    App::import('Model', 'EmailSave');

    $this->EmailSave = new EmailSave();
    $this->User      = new User();

    $users  = $this->User->find("all", array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'OR' => array(
                array('User.user_type_id' => '4'),
                array('User.user_type_id' => '1')
            ) 
        ),
        'fields' => array(
            'username',
            'email'
        ),
        'recursive' => -1
    ));

    foreach($users as $user){
        //pr($user);
        $to         = $user['User']['email'];
        $subject    = $email_template['subject'];
        $template   = //calling a templating method;

        $save_send['EmailSave']['created']    = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
        $save_send['EmailSave']['modified']   = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
        $save_send['EmailSave']['send_to']    = $to;
        $save_send['EmailSave']['subject']    = $subject;
        $save_send['EmailSave']['message']    = $template;

        //pr($save_send);
        $this->EmailSave->save($save_send);
        //echo $to."<br />".$subject."<br />".$template."<br />".$cron_id."<br />";
    }
}
```

this is pretty much straight forward, i mean i am not using any complicated methods, now when i run the find method towards user :

```
$users  = $this->User->find("all", array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'OR' => array(
                    array('User.user_type_id' => '4'),
                    array('User.user_type_id' => '1')
                ) 
            ),
            'fields' => array(
                'username',
                'email'
            ),
            'recursive' => -1
        ));
```

it returns 2 results, and when i try to print the result using cake's pr method, it would print the right results, but...if i apply the save method, it would only insert one of the result, how is that possible? i have traced the codes line by line and it went through just find, the problem is when i save them to the database, it fails to save all 2 results, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data

> Creating or updating is controlled by the model's id field. If `$Model->id` is set, the record with this primary key is updated. Otherwise a new record is created.
>
> **When calling `save()` in a loop, don't forget to call `create()`.**